# Is the term "restricted interest" not redundant?

Tags: word-meaning, definition

Here is a quote from an article on [Wikipedia on Asperger's Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asperger_syndrome):

> People with Asperger syndrome often display **restricted** or specialized
>   **interests**, such as this boy's interest in stacking cans.

[image]

As far as I know, the word "restricted" has two meanings in English: the first one is "forbidden" and the second one is "limited to a certain area or field".

Obviously, here it's not the first meaning.

But then I am not sure I understand how the second meaning works here. I mean an interest is by definition something limited to a certain field, isn't it?

For example, if I am interested in pop-music, than it is just natural that I don't have a similar degree of interest toward other fields like, say, culinary and photography.

In fact, if my interest were not limited to those fields that I am curious about and were equally distributed among all fields instead, then it would look more like I had not particular interest toward anything at all!

So, is the term "restricted interest" not redundant?

Comment: I'm not sure "restricted" ever means literally "forbidden". When we say that an area is "restricted" we mean that access is restricted to a limited set of persons. Yes, it is forbidden to all others, but "restricted" does not mean "forbidden".

Answer (score 2):

If your interest in pop music is to the exclusion of all else, yes, it's restricted.  Most people have many and varied interests.

Restricted interests are not just not being interested in everything but being interested in just about nothing.

Comment: “If your interest in pop music is to the exclusion of all else, yes, it's restricted” – But, having read, through this whole wiki article, I can’t say that it means the “exclusion of all else”. Do you think stacking cans is the only interest in life that the boy on the picture has? I don’t think so. At least, I don’t gather that idea from that article.

Comment: “Restricted interests are not just not being interested in everything but being interested in just about nothing.” – I don’t see much logic in this statement. The boy on the picture has at least an interest in stacking cans. How is it “being interested in just about nothing” then?

Comment: An interest in pop music is not restricted, but if you had an obsession with one band or singer to the exclusion of all others, that would be a restricted interest.

Comment: @KateBunting - What do you mean by "exclusion of all others"? If I have an interest toward only one girl and want exactly her to become my wife and, thus, exclude all others from being a candidate to be my wife, would this also then be a case of restricted interest? If to the question "What's your favorite animal?" I name only one animal and, thus, exclude all other animals from being my favorite, will it be the case of restricted interest? Is that really that abnormal to have only one favorite animal or to have only one hobby?

Comment: Of course the concept doesn't apply to choosing a spouse or naming a favourite. A person who is 'interested in pop music' normally enjoys listening to a variety of different performers. I was trying to explain that an autistic person's interest would only be regarded as 'restricted' if, for example, they insisted on only ever listening to one artist.

Comment: @KateBunting - What if it's only pop music and not any other kinds of music, would that also be a case of restricted interest?

Comment: No, preferring a particular genre of music is not unusual.

Comment: @brilliant  Photographs have limited ability to illustrate the point -- such as merely being able to show him stacking the cans and not that it is a monomania.

Comment: I think this answer answers the basic issue. Restricted interests as opposed to broad interest or a wide range of interests.

Answer (score 0):

Many people have interests in a number of things, and not in other things. However the word "interests" is only positive; it is within the meaning of the word for somebody to be interested in everything. While describing somebody's interests as "restricted" could be taken to mean merely that they are not interested in everything, that is not what it means in this context. Here it means that the person has a significantly narrower range of interests than the majority of people.

In a similar way describing a person's view as restricted means that they can see only some of what is in front of them, not that they cannot see things that are behind them.